# Java: object creation causes runtime error

Tags: java, object, runtime-error

I am new to Java and I am trying some examples to understand how it works.

I am having problems understanding why the following code fails. I know the line that causes the error but I can't tell why. I made two classes, `Class1` and `Main`, whose code is written in two separate .java files:

```
public class Class1
{
    int var;
    public void method1 ()
    {
        System.out.println(var);
    }
    Class1 obj1 = new Class1(); // this is the line that causes the error
}
```

and

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Class1 obj = new Class1();
        obj.method1();
    }
}
```

It compiles fine, but when I run `java Main` it just prints hundreds of times the error

```
at Class1.<init>(Class1.java:8)
```

I tried running `java Main | more` (I am using Unix Bash) but the pipe gets somehow ignored and I can't see the first line of the error message. Nor does `java Main > log.txt` output redirection to a text file work. If I remove that line, i.e. if I don't create the `Class1` object `obj1` in the `Class1` class body, everything works fine. Can anyone explain to me what's wrong with that line?

Thank you

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your answers, I got it now.

Comment: Is there a reason for the question being downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are creating Class1 object in an infinite loop.

When you create an Class1 object in main method, it initializes all variables you have defined in Class1 body. But since you also create a new Class1 object inside of Class1 body, it keeps creating Class1 object and at some point, it will cause stack overflow error.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have a recursive `Object` initialization.

`Class1 obj = new Class1();` is an instance statement, so it's called at every instance, recursively, initiated from your `main` method.

This will cause a `StackOverflowError`.

The `StackOverflowError` is the JVM's way of telling you you are overflowing the stack memory, and the easiest way to trigger one is through infinite method or constructor recursion, such as in your case.

Answer (score 1):

this is illegal to do     `Class1 obj1 = new Class1();` at the class level of the same class

you should not create the object in the class level of the same class.its allowed to create reference like     `Class1 obj1;` at class level of the same class

Answer (score 1):

That is effectively an infinite loop there in that you create a new instance of the class inside every new instance of the class eventually Java runs out of memory or stack and throws an exception.

Answer (score 1):

You code will eventually throw:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

Because of unconditional recursive initialization attempts.

To complete class construction it needs to complete this initialization:

```
Class1 obj1 = new Class1();
```

Which in turn will try to construct `Class1` again and this vivacious cycle will continue until JVM give up with **`java.lang.StackOverflowError`**.